# Output not registering integers bigger than 99

Tags: python

I am trying to code ticket prices depending on a persons gender and age. I coded the following:

```
sex=(input("What gender are you?: ")).lower()
age=(input("What age are you?: "))
priceofticket=100

if sex=="male":
    print ("Male ticket price is")
    if age>= "60":
        print(priceofticket*.7, "for senior citizen")
    elif age<="60":
        print(priceofticket, "for normal citizen")
        
if sex=="female":
    print ("Female ticket price is")
    if age>= "60":
        print(priceofticket*.5, "for senior citizen")
    elif age >"60":
        print(priceofticket*.7, "for senior citizen")
```

This code works fine UNTIL the age goes above 99. After 99 it doesnt return any number. I put a "" around 60 because it wont take an integer data type saying i cannot use str and int together. I think this is the problem but i'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your sample input, expected output and actual output.

Comment: string "100" is smaller than string "60". Convert the age to `int` type, then compare it with number `60`

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing strings for age, rather than ints.

```
>>> "100" > "6"
False
```

Comparison of strings means the above compares `"1"` to `"6"` and finds `"100"` to *not* be greater than `"65"`.

```
sex = input("What gender are you?: ").lower()
age = int(input("What age are you?: "))
priceofticket = 100

if sex == "male":
    print("Male ticket price is")
    if age >= 60:
        print(priceofticket * .7, "for senior citizen")
    elif age <= 60:
        print(priceofticket, "for normal citizen")
        
if sex == "female":
    print("Female ticket price is")
    if age >= 60:
        print(priceofticket * .5, "for senior citizen")
    elif age > 60:
        print(priceofticket * .7, "for senior citizen")
```

There are some other issues with your code.

- When checking the age, you do not need `elif` but can rather just use `else`.
- You *can* use `elif` for the `sex == "female"` condition.
- f-strings are your friends when printing.

```
sex = input("What gender are you?: ").lower()
age = int(input("What age are you?: "))
priceofticket = 100

if sex == "male":
    print("Male ticket price is")
    if age >= 60:
        print(f"{priceofticket * .7} for senior citizen")
    else:
        print(f"{priceofticket} for normal citizen")
elif sex == "female":
    print("Female ticket price is")
    if age >= 60:
        print(f"{priceofticket * .5} for senior citizen")
    else:
        print(f"{priceofticket * .7} for senior citizen")
```

You may also wish to flatten your nested conditionals.

```
sex = input("What gender are you?: ").lower()
age = int(input("What age are you?: "))
priceofticket = 100

if sex == "male" and age >= 60:
    print("Male ticket price is")
    print(f"{priceofticket * .7} for senior citizen")
elif sex == "male":
    print("Male ticket price is")
    print(f"{priceofticket} for normal citizen")
elif sex == "female" and age >= 60:
    print("Female ticket price is")
    print(f"{priceofticket * .5} for senior citizen")
elif sex == "female":
    print("Female ticket price is")
    print(f"{priceofticket * .7} for senior citizen")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse age variable as int type.
Your code should be like the following code:

```
sex= input("What gender are you?: ").lower()
age= int(input("What age are you?: "))
priceofticket=100

if sex=="male":
    print ("Male ticket price is")
    if age >= 60:
        print(priceofticket*.7, "for senior citizen")
    elif age <= 60:
        print(priceofticket, "for normal citizen")

if sex=="female":
    print ("Female ticket price is")
    if age>= 60:
        print(priceofticket*.5, "for senior citizen")
    elif age > 60:
        print(priceofticket*.7, "for senior citizen")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the input from the user formatted as a string against the string "60", convert the user's input into a number, verify that it works, then compare it against 60 as an integer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert `age` to an `int`eger and compare it with integers.

(Also, those `else`s can use a bit of simplifying, and there was a copy-paste error in the prose for the female non-senior branch. :-) )

```
sex = (input("What gender are you?: ")).lower()
age = int(input("What age are you?: "))
priceofticket = 100

if sex == "male":
    print("Male ticket price is")
    if age >= 60:
        print(priceofticket * 0.7, "for senior citizen")
    else:
        print(priceofticket, "for normal citizen")

if sex == "female":
    print("Female ticket price is")
    if age >= 60:
        print(priceofticket * 0.5, "for senior citizen")
    else:
        print(priceofticket * 0.7, "for normal citizen")
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'age' variable is treated as a string and both the if and else branches are failing due to string comparison logic, and hence nothing is printed.

Change the second line to:

```
age=int(input("What age are you?: "))
```

And remove the quotes around the numbers in the if..else.. conditions.